# Selenium fails to click a checkbox under a fixed footer

Tags: firefox, testing, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I'm automating tests using Selenium on Firefox, and everything was working ok until I needed to check checkboxes that are not visible due to a footer that is fixed to the bottom of the page.

It's a long list of disclaimers that are necessary to be checked in order to continue.

The first two are below this footer, the rest forces a scroll down, and are checked correctly.

My question is:

1) Is there a way to check the first two even thought they are below the footer?
2) Is there a way to make Selenium scroll down using a command?
3) Is there a way to make Selenium to open a new Firefox window maximized? (I believe that if this is possible, all checkboxes will be visible on load)

Thank you!

PS: This is my second post, if I'm missing some information please let me know and I'll edit it.

EDIT:

Firefox version: 23.0.1
Webdriver version: 2.35

Unfortunately, i have only configured my webdriver for Firefox (not on chrome at the moment)

Comment: What code are you using? What version of Selenium? What version of Firefox? What site are you running against? Is this reproducible elsewhere on a site that has a similar design? Any different results in say, Chrome? IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to scroll the page as long as you are finding the Element with correct selectors (e.g. xpath, css etc.), so something like `driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));` should remove the need to scroll the page. As for opening the page in full screen use the following

`driver.manage().window().maximize();`

Comment: Thank you! this somehow fixed it! No before doing anything maximizes the browser so that the element is visible!

Answer (score 1):

If your web page needs to be scrolled down to interact with element, first you'll have to bring that element into view. Using Ruby, this can be achieved by following:

```
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

and then interact with element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript executor to scroll the page.  I've found that Selenium will click objects that are "visible" but hidden behind something else on the page.

```
JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsx.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,450)", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the capability:

```
capabilities.setCapability("elementScrollBehavior", 1); // 0- from Top,
                                                      // 1 - from bottom
```

When I start the driver, I set the capability.